# Tuples indexing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to to put json data into a tuple and print it.

```
dict_all = json.loads(jsonFormat)
index = 0
for data in dict_all:
    key = tuple((dict_all[index]['package_size_code'],
    dict_all[index]['fda_ther_equiv_code'], 
    dict_all[index]['fda_application_number'],
    dict_all[index]['clotting_factor_indicator'],
    dict_all[index]['year'],
    dict_all[index]['fda_product_name'],
    dict_all[index]['labeler_name'],
...
    index = index + 1
print(key)
```

The output is:

```
    ('60', 'NR', '204153', 'N', '2018', 'LUZU Cream 1% 60gm', 'MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.', '99207085060', '0850', 'GM', '2013-11-14T00:00:00', '2014-03-14T00:00:00', 'N', '2014-03-14T00:00:00', '60000', '99207', '1', 'S', '2', '3')
    ('60', 'AB', '21758', 'N', '2018', 'VANOS CREAM .1%', 'MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.', '99207052560', '0525', 'GM', '2005-02-11T00:00:00', '2005-02-21T00:00:00', 'N', '2005-02-21T00:00:00', '60000', '99207', '1', 'I', '2', '3')
....
```

Seems fine so far. But when I try to print key[0], I get values:

```
60
60
...
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
('60', 'NR', '204153', 'N', '2018', 'LUZU Cream 1% 60gm', 'MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.', '99207085060', '0850', 'GM', '2013-11-14T00:00:00', '2014-03-14T00:00:00', 'N', '2014-03-14T00:00:00', '60000', '99207', '1', 'S', '2', '3')
```

One row is a element in the tuple. I would like it to be as shown above. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: ``key`` is just a single tuple - you see several because you call ``print(key)`` for each index! Using ``key[0]`` gets you the first element of the key tuple, but again once for each index.

Comment: You are not saving your `key` variable anywhere. You just overwrite it each time round the loop.

Comment: No, `key` is first `('60', 'NR', '204153', ...)` and you do `key[0]` which is `60`. Next time, `key` is the next tuple and `key[0]` is still `60`.

Comment: Ohhh the print placed in the loop confused me. I thought it was outside. Still not used to python synthax.

Comment: Actually, the print you've provided here *is* outside the loop, so this code should have only printed the last value of `key`.

Comment: What an embarrasing mistake. The provided answer is what I am been trying to do. I think tuple is not necessary here where list will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have meant to do this:

```
dict_all = json.loads(jsonFormat)
index = 0
key = []
for data in dict_all:
    key.append(tuple((dict_all[index]['package_size_code'],
    dict_all[index]['fda_ther_equiv_code'], 
    dict_all[index]['fda_application_number'],
    dict_all[index]['clotting_factor_indicator'],
    dict_all[index]['year'],
    dict_all[index]['fda_product_name'],
    dict_all[index]['labeler_name'],
    ...
    )
    index = index + 1

print(key)
print(key[0])
```

The `key` variable is now a list which above gets printed out once after the loop has finished. And as an example, prints the first element of the list.

Comment: Thanks. I should have used list from the very beginning.

Comment: I was actually trying to use tuple as Sqlite3 uses them for inserts but it looks like list itself is enough.

Comment: So tuples are not needed at all. I am just doing what you did but without the tuple thing.